# Dynamic menu binding using oledb in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, oracle

if I am using Sql Server database in asp.net for dynamic menu binding it shows menus and submenus items on page.but on the other side if I use oracle database for menu binding it does not shows menu items on page.it shows menu control blank at run time

**Sql Connectivity**

```
try
{
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    string connStr = "server=webserver;uid=sa;pwd=sa;database=amit;";
    using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    {

        string sql = "Select Menuid, subheadname, Description, ParentID, url from Menumaster where typeno like '%" + Session["user_type"].ToString().Trim() + "%' and prno is not null";
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
        da.Fill(ds);
        da.Dispose();
    }

    ds.DataSetName = "Menus";
    ds.Tables[0].TableName = "Menu";
    DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("ParentChild",
                                    ds.Tables[0].Columns["Menuid"],
                                    ds.Tables[0].Columns["ParentID"], false);

    relation.Nested = true;
    ds.Relations.Add(relation);
    xmlDataSource.Data = ds.GetXml();
}
catch
{
    Response.Redirect("Error.aspx");
}
```

**oracle connectivity**

```
Try
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Dim constr As String = 
        System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionString("ConnectionString").ConnectionString
    Dim ds As DataSet = New DataSet()
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(constr)
        Dim str As String = "Select Menuid, subheadname,Description, ParentID,url from dtl_Menumaster where prno is not null ORDER BY MENUID"
        Dim da As OleDbDataAdapter = New OleDbDataAdapter(str, conn)
        da.Fill(ds)
        da.Dispose()
    End Using

    ds.DataSetName = "Menus"
    ds.Tables(0).TableName = "Menu"
    Dim relation As DataRelation = New DataRelation("ParentChild",
    ds.Tables(0).Columns("Menuid"),
    ds.Tables(0).Columns("ParentID"), True)

    relation.Nested = True
    ds.Relations.Add(relation)
    xmlDataSource.Data = ds.GetXml()
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

Comment: Does your oracle db has values?

Comment: Yes oracle db table has values

Comment: I suppose you use odbc for oracle. Check and be sure for odbc connection "looks" to the right database. Your code seems to me ok.

Comment: I have been used both connections oledb and odbc but my menu items not   showing,even my dataset is correctly filled

Comment: but by using sql connection, menu items correctly shows on page,but when i use oledb,oracle or odbc connection my menu items not shows on page.please help me